# Google Shared Drive Push Notifications only Sending for Service Account Changes

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to get push notifications anytime a file is added to our shared drive by any user.

I have a service account authenticated with the Google Drive API calling the [changes.watch()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch) method on the shared drive, and I successfully get notifications if the shared drive name or icon changes, a file is created by the service account, or if files are modified by any user so long as the service account created the file. However, I do not get any push notifications for files created on this shared drive by other users - even though the page token increases and calling changes.list() will show me the changes that all users made on the shared drive.

I have the shared drive shared with the service account, and the service account also has domain-wide delegation for the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive and uses that scope in the API call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out what I'm lacking to get push notifications for all changes on this shared drive. Below is my code related to authenticating and subscribing to change notifications.

```
import urllib

from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account

import uuid
from datetime import datetime

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_file_location)

    scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(scopes)
    service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials=scoped_credentials)

    return service


def get_start_page_token(service):
    response = service.changes().getStartPageToken(
        driveId = "REDACTED",
        supportsAllDrives = True,
        supportsTeamDrives = True
        ).execute()
    startPageToken = response.get("startPageToken")
    print(F'Start token: {startPageToken}')
    return startPageToken

def subscribe_changes(service):
    channel_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    body = {
        "id": channel_id,
        "type": "web_hook",
        "address": "https://REDACTED"
    }

    response = service.changes().watch(
          body=body, 
          pageToken = get_start_page_token(service),
          includeItemsFromAllDrives = True,
          supportsAllDrives = True,
          supportsTeamDrives = True,
          driveId = "REDACTED"
        ).execute()

    ts = int(response['expiration'])
    print("Expiration in UTC: " + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    print(response)
    return channel_id



# Define the auth scopes to request.
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
key_file_location = 'credentials.json'

try:
    # Authenticate and construct service.
    service = get_service(
        api_name='drive',
        api_version='v3',
        scopes=[scope],
        key_file_location=key_file_location)

except HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


# subscribe to changes
channel_id = subscribe_changes(service)
print(f"Channel Id: {channel_id}")
```